# Background-image not showing up in sidebar

Tags: css

In the sidebar, I have tried adding background-image but it doesn't show up for the title. I wonder what is causing it. The following will not work. However, applying a background color does work as well. I've tried background-image property, doesn't work as well.

```
.title-widget {
  background: #fff url('http://www.hawthornfc.com.au/static-resources/themes/hawthorn/images/bg-section-header.gif);
}
```

Go to my website below for the live view. Also, for the marquee text, upon scrolling down, it overlaps the fixed header. I've applied z-index but it still doesn't seem to go behind the header.

Website: http://www.nbtfootball.com.sg/wwfc/

Comment: Missing closing quote in url() ?

Comment: Also, try to split the `background` rule into `background-color` and `background-image`, then use your browser's inspector to change both and see if it has any effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the closing quote in the url();

try:

```
.title-widget {
  background: #fff url('http://www.hawthornfc.com.au/static-resources/themes/hawthorn/images/bg-section-header.gif');
}
```

Comment: +1 : i was about to comment that its mentioned in comments already... *before i matched the name* !! :)

Comment: I went and checked using element inspector that it was definitly that and only posted answer once i'd confirmed it was the exact issue and the image wasn't 404 or something else as well. :)